# ansible - archive files, with a dated filename, by archive date

Tags: date, ansible, archive

I want to archive all files, containing a date in their names, present in a same folder, in the same archive by date with Ansible.

Let me explain:

Files can be of this type:
(attention the date can be separated by dashes or underscores)

```
/app/logs/app.log
/app/logs/app.log.2018-12-04
/app/logs/app.log.2018-12-05
/app/logs/batch.log
/app/logs/batch.log.2018-12-04
/app/logs/batch.log.2018-12-05
/app/logs/web.log
/app/logs/web.log.2018_12_04
/app/logs/web.log.2018_12_05
```

I want archive files, with ansible, containing a date like this:

```
/app/logs/20181204.tar.gz
/app/logs/20181205.tar.gz
```

For the moment I search files :

```
- name: Search files
  find:
    paths: "/app/logs/"
  register: files
```

I try to build new dictionary :

```
- set_fact:
  file:
    - "name": "{{ item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') }}"
      "path": [ "{{ item.path }}" ]
  loop: "{{ files.files }}"
  when: item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') != ''
```

And archive my files, but my var file contains only one file

```
- name: archive logs
  archive:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "/app/logs/{{ item.name }}.tar.gz"
  with_items: "{{ file }}"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And archive my files, but my var file contains only one file

That's because you're setting the variable `file` to a single value:

```
- set_fact:
  file:
    - "name": "{{ item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') }}"
      "path": [ "{{ item.path }}" ]
  loop: "{{ files.files }}"
  when: item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') != ''
```

Just putting `set_fact` in a loop doesn't change the fact that you are
setting `file` to the single value `{{ item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') }}`.

If you want the result of your `set_fact` task to be a list, you need
to build a list. Something like this might work:

```
- set_fact:
    files_list: "{{
      (files_list|default([])) +
      [{
      'name': item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , ''),
      'path': item.path
      }]
      }}"
    loop: "{{ files.files }}"
    when: item.path | basename | regex_replace( '[A-Z-_.a-z]' , '') != ''
```

That will create the `files_list` list variable by appending a
dictionary to it for each iteration of your `loop`.

Answer (score 0):

finally i need only the 2nd list files_list

```
- name: archive logs in zip
  archive:
    path: "{{ item[1]|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
    dest: "/app/logs/{{ item[0] }}.zip"
   format: zip
  loop: "{{ grouped }}"
  vars:
    grouped: "{{ files_list|groupby('name') }}"
```

Thanks Larsks the second list is yours :)